# Remove " Automatically Extracted Metadata and Version History " from Liferay portlet

Tags: liferay

i want to remove the " Automatically Extracted Metadata and Version History " and the things like : 
" Version 1.0 
Last Updated by Admin 
5/5/15 5:24 PM 
Status: Approved
Download (911k)  Get URL or WebDAV URL." form the Documents and Media Portlet. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

As posted here:
http://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/26039804

Remove the com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.RawMetadataProcessorImpl from the dl.file.entry.processors in portal-ext.properties

```
# Input a list of comma delimited class names that implement
# com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.DLProcessor. These classes will
# trigger asynchronous processing for document library files.
#
# com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.PDFProcessor will process all
# PDF files and, if OpenOffice is enabled, all formats convertable to PDF.
# Image generation will use PDFBox by default unless ImageMagick is enabled.
# PDFBox is less accurate in image generation and has trouble with certain
# fonts.
#
dl.file.entry.processors=com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.AudioProcessorImpl,com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.ImageProcessorImpl,com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.PDFProcessorImpl,com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.RawMetadataProcessorImpl,com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.VideoProcessorImpl
```

Another Approach would be to hook the Document Library and remove the relevant parts from the jsp.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i have no portal.properties.ext !

Comment: Can u suggest a method through the css?

Comment: For a CSS solution: Use Firebug (or equivalent) to identify the DOM selectors, and add that selector with a "display:none;" to your theme's CSS.